# Best way to return 2 objects inside a response body in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, web

I want to send 2 objects (instances of 2 different classes) inside POST request body, process the information and the send back the updated objects in response. What is the best way of doing that ? I know I can put the objects in a map or create a wrapper object, but probably there is a more graceful way of achieving that.

Example of a request body:

```
{
  "object1": {
    "data1": "val1",
    "data2": "val2"
  },
  "object2": {
    "dataN": "valN"
  }
}
```

Example of a response body:

```
{
  "object1": {
    "data1": "updatedVal1",
    "data2": "val2"
  },
  "object2": {
    "dataN": "updatedValN"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the relationship between these two different objects? Why, in a REST sense, does it make sense to send both back?

Comment: You own example of sending back 2 objects is basically an object containing 2 json objects. It never makes sense to send two objects in one response, just create two different requests and 2 different responses, unless both of these objects are part of one bigger object in which case you should use the wrapper class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no graceful way of sending two java objects. Using a POJO is graceful enough. There's nothing wrong with having many POJOs that represent specific things. Using POJOs is a better practice than using a Map since it provides type safety. And if you use the `lombok` library you can eliminate all the boilerplate code so your POJO is nice and small:

```
@Data
public class TwoResponse {
  private OneType object1;
  private TwoType object2;
}
```